# Using Script Task to create ADO NET (ODBC) Data Flow Source

Tags: ado.net, ssis, pervasive-sql

I need some help with a SSIS Script Task (SQL 2008 R2) that dynamically creates a package.  I am refining a package that copies data from a Sage Timberline (Now rebranded to Sage 300) Pervasive SQL environment to a SQL server data warehouse.  I can create a package that opens the connection to Timberline and copies the data to a table in SQL Server.  The problem is, for each company in timberline and each table in SQL, I need to create a separate data flow task.  Given the three Timberline company folders and the number of tables in each folder, this would take a lot of time to create and be cumbersome to maintain and troubleshoot.

I am trying to create a package that uses a Foreach Loop to create a package that creates  a ADO/ODBC source (Timberline), a OLE destination (SQL) and dynamically handles the column mapping.  I found code [here](http://www.sqllion.com/2009/05/ssis-programming-basic/) that almost does what I need.

I tested this code and it works great using OLE SQL source and destinations.  What makes this script work is that it dynamically handles the column mapping.  So, it you placed it into a Foreach Loop of the 100 or so tables, with each loop it could dynamically create the data flow and map the columns, then execute the new package.

My problem is that I can only connect to Timberline using ODBC.  So, I need to modify the script to create the source connection with ADO NET (ODBC) instead of OLE.  I’m having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out.  Could someone please help me out with this?

Here the other couple of things I tried first, other than this approach:

Solution: Setup a Linked server to Timberline Pervasive SQL
Problem:  SQL server is 64-bit and the Timberline driver is 32-bit.  Using a linked server returns a architecture mismatch error.  I called Sage and they said they have no plans to release a 64-bit drive.

Solution: Use one of the SQL Transfer tasks
Problem: Only works with SQL databases.  This source is a Pervasive SQL database

Solution:  Use a “INSERT … INTO …” type script
Problem:  This requires a linked server.  See the problem above

Here’s the section of the [original VB .NET code](http://www.sqllion.com/2009/05/ssis-programming-basic/) I need help with:

```
'To Create a package named [Sample Package]
Dim package As New Package()
package.Name = "Sample Package"
package.PackageType = DTSPackageType.DTSDesigner100
package.VersionBuild = 1

'To add Connection Manager to the package
'For source database (OLTP)
Dim OLTP As ConnectionManager = package.Connections.Add("OLEDB")
OLTP.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OLTP;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
OLTP.Name = "LocalHost.OLTP"

'To add Load Employee Dim to the package [Data Flow Task]
Dim dataFlowTaskHost As TaskHost = DirectCast(package.Executables.Add("SSIS.Pipeline.2"), TaskHost)
dataFlowTaskHost.Name = "Load Employee Dim"
dataFlowTaskHost.FailPackageOnFailure = True
dataFlowTaskHost.FailParentOnFailure = True
dataFlowTaskHost.DelayValidation = False
dataFlowTaskHost.Description = "Data Flow Task"

'-----------Data Flow Inner component starts----------------
Dim dataFlowTask As MainPipe = TryCast(dataFlowTaskHost.InnerObject, MainPipe)
' Source OLE DB connection manager to the package.
Dim SconMgr As ConnectionManager = package.Connections("LocalHost.OLTP")

' Create and configure an OLE DB source component.
Dim source As IDTSComponentMetaData100 = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.[New]()
source.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OLEDBSource.2"

' Create the design-time instance of the source.
Dim srcDesignTime As CManagedComponentWrapper = source.Instantiate()
' The ProvideComponentProperties method creates a default output.
srcDesignTime.ProvideComponentProperties()
source.Name = "Employee Dim from OLTP"

' Assign the connection manager.
source.RuntimeConnectionCollection(0).ConnectionManagerID = SconMgr.ID
source.RuntimeConnectionCollection(0).ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(SconMgr)
' Set the custom properties of the source.
srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 0)
' Mode 0 : OpenRowset / Table - View
srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", "[dbo].[Employee_Dim]")
' Connect to the data source, and then update the metadata for the source.
srcDesignTime.AcquireConnections(Nothing)
srcDesignTime.ReinitializeMetaData()
srcDesignTime.ReleaseConnections()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The C# code here is what you need if you need a Derived Column transform between the Source and Destination...

http://bifuture.blogspot.com/2011/01/ssis-adding-derived-column-to-ssis.html

To get the Source & Destination connections working, there is some secret sauce here to get things working between COM and .Net...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/api-sample-ado-net-source.aspx
There is a similar page showing what to do for OleDB connections too.

Creating the source tables is easy. The available ODBC Metadata collections accessible should be retrieved with GetSchema("MetaDataCollections"). This will return a list of the available schema collections available for that particular ODBC driver.
Next, you'll want to see the data types returned from GetSchema("DataTypes"), so you can correctly interpret the data types for each column retrieved from GetSchema("Columns") to make your SQL Server create table script (which I'm assuming you've done).
To at least figure out which tables have primary keys, you'll need to loop over each table returned from GetSchema("Tables") in order to work with GetSchema("Indexes"). There's a bug that requires you to query the Indexes one table at a time. It is easy to google this  - create a string array to pass in as the 3rd parameter: GetSchema("Indexes", tblName, resultArray[])

What I did was got the Tables and Columns collections into object variables in my parent SSIS package. Because Timberline is so fast (not), it seemed more efficient to pull all the columns down and filter them locally...which I do to create the tables in SQL Server, if necessary.

Once that is done, use the local copy of Tables again to manipulate a SSIS package in a Script task in "design mode" (change source and destination target tables, and redo the column mappings), and execute the now-in-memory SSIS package.

For me it took awhile to figure out. Both above URLs were required. I found and copied the .Net 2.0 Dts.PipelineWrap and Dts.RuntimeWrap .dlls to Microsoft.Net\FrameworkV2.0xxxxx folder, then referenced these in each script task wanting to use them, before setting up my "using DtsPW = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper", etc.

Of note, because Timberline is 32-bit ODBC, I think it's necessary to build the SSIS package to use "X86", and target the script tasks to use .Net 2.0 framework.

I used the Derived Column code because I needed to copy multiple Timberline DBs into one SQL Server DB. Derived Column adds a "CompanyID" value to the output pipeline to SQL Server.

In the end, map the Destination's Virtual Input columns to its External Metadata columns, based off of the pipeline the Destination is attached to:

```
      foreach (DtsPW.IDTSVirtualInputColumn100 vColumn in destVirtInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection)
            {
                var vCol = destInst.SetUsageType(destInput.ID, destVirtInput, vColumn.LineageID, DtsPW.DTSUsageType.UT_READWRITE);
                destInst.MapInputColumn(destInput.ID, vCol.ID, destInput.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection[vColumn.Name].ID);

            }
```

Anyways, that code will make more sense in the context of the bifuture.blogspot.com page.

The EzApi library could help with this too, but the AdoNet connection source for it is coded as a virtual class, so you'd need to implement specific classes to use. My C# kungfu is not strong enough for that in the time I have...

Also, CozyRoc sells a toolset with custom SSIS controls (data flow Source and Destination controls...) that looks like it does this on the fly input-to-output column mapping as well.

My package seems to work good enough now... Oh, and one more, I did not have luck trying to use DSN-less ODBC connections to Timberline, just: Dsn=dsnname;Uid=user;Pwd=pwd;

SSIS packages running in 64-bit land cannot see 32-bit DSNs on 64-bit OS, it seems...at least, it didn't work for me (win7-64, 32-bit Text ODBC DSN).